# Display data on html table from different tables MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have a html table and I need to display different data from different tables.

This is the table:

[image]

I used viewmodel here, I was able to display some of the data but I need to display everything.

How can I display data from Delivery, Collection, and Proposal tables?

Here's my viewmodel:

```
public class FulfillmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.ProductModel> Product { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.ProposalModel> Proposal { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.Delivery> Delivery { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.Collection> Collection { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Institution> Institution { get; set; }

}
```

This is my code on the VIEW:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="th-center">
                            <th colspan="2">Product</th>
                            <th colspan="3">Purchase Order</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Delivery</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Collection</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="th-center">
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Proposal Code</th>
                            <th>PO Number</th>
                            <th>PO Date</th>
                            <th>Received Date</th>
                            <th>SI Number</th>
                            <th>Delivery Date</th>
                            <th>OR Number</th>
                            <th>OR Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach(var PO in Model.PurchaseOrder)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>Anflu</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><a href="fulfillment–delivery-and-collection-details.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => PO.PurchaseOrderNo)</a></td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => PO.PurchaseOrderDate)</td>                                                                                                
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => PO.ReceivedDate)</td>
                            <td>SI-0002314</td>
                            <td>December 20, 2013</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <a href="edit-purchase-order.html"><img src="Images/icon_edit.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
                                <a href="new-delivery.html"><img src="Images/icon-delivery.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
                                <a href="new-collection.html"><img src="Images/icon-collection.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }



                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to combine the `Delivery`, `Collection` and `Proposal` into a separate class and then include this new class in your `ViewModel`. You would then enumerate through the `ItemModel`'s and be able to access the related `Product`, `Delivery` and `Collection`.

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ULIV.Models.ProductModel Product { get; set; }
    public ULIV.Models.Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    public ULIV.Models.Collection Collection { get; set; }
}

public class FulfillmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.ProposalModel> Proposal { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ULIV.Models.PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Institution> Institution { get; set; }
```

}